# In Exchange (2003) how do I list the forms used in the public folder tree?

Tags: reporting, exchange-server, scripting

Does anyone have a script or can anyone point me in the right direction to query an Exchange (2003) public folder tree to determine all the forms being used ?

I need an output of form object/display name and count for each form type in each folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) a try. It should be suitable for what you need.